# Android Development: How To Add App To The Application Chooser?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, launch, file-browser

Basically I want to add my application to the application chooser list for files with the type .php, .java, .js, .html etc. so that users can browse for a file using any file browser and use my app to open it.

I've looked at tutorials for Broadcast Receivers but none of them have shown how to do this, they've just shown how to listen for the phone state changing and stuff.

Help! :(

Thanks,
Alex!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I never used it, I think this might help you: [Intent-Filters](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/intents/intents-filters.html#ifs).

And also [this thread](http://www.anddev.org/novice-tutorials-f8/associating-a-file-with-android-application-t12972.html) from anddev.org.

Comment: Thanks, the source code of the FBReaderJ application helped :)